# Can't post a comment unless you have 50 points?

Tags: discussion

I am posting this question here because I cant ask a question within tne neta site (which I believe is the correct place for this question) as I dont have 5 points!

I joined this site in order to post a comment on a thread I amk interested in only to find that I need 50 points in order to do so, which is strange as I wish to answer a post and not ask a question.  :-(

SK

Comment: New users can indeed only post questions and answers and no comments until they reach a certain [minimum privilege level](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges) and commenting everywhere requires > 50 points. That is by design. By the way: you can always comment on *your own* questions and answers.

Comment: It also serves as a **motivation** for you to track the next privilege and tackle it by finding and answering questions you can (which helps someone somewhere )

Comment: If you wish to **answer** a question, then answer it. No need to post a comment. But before doing so, ensure that your answer truly does actually provide a real answer to the question. If it doesn't, the answer will be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  What prompted me to raise this question was becuase I could not see how I could post an answer to the following question:-  

https://serverfault.com/questions/821184/windows-server-2016-scheduled-task-schedule-must-be-in-future

After reviewing it again today though, I have embarrassingly found out why that is:  

"Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site. "  


As I dont have 10 points I cannot post an answer.  As I dont have 50 points I cannot post a comment.

Comment: Just find some other question to which you are able to provide a constructive answer. 10 rep is really quite easy to get; all it takes is a single upvote on a single answer, or two upvotes on a question.